# "Old Mr. Bunny had no opinion whatever of cats." What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

In "The Tale of Benjamin Bunny" Beatrix Potter writes "Old Mr. Bunny had no opinion whatever of cats." What does it mean?

> The cat looked up and saw old Mr. Benjamin Bunny prancing along the
>   top of the wall of the upper terrace.
>
> He was smoking a pipe of rabbit-tobacco, and had a little switch in
>   his hand.
>
> He was looking for his son. Old Mr. Bunny **had no opinion whatever of** 
>   **cats.**
>
> He took a tremendous jump off the top of the wall on to the top of the
>   cat, and cuffed it off the basket, and kicked it into the green-house,
>   scratching off a handful of fur.
>
> The cat was too much surprised to scratch back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking in Google books, many of the instances of "had no opinion whatever of" X mean that he literally didn't have any opinion of X. However, there are a few instances of this phrase meaning "did not think highly of X"<sup>1</sup>. For instance, [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=fm5IAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA187&dq=%22had+no+opinion+whatever%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ftRHT8DUD4T0ggfEguSFDg&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22had%20no%20opinion%20whatever%22&f=false) gives (*Blackwood's Edinburgh magazine,* 1885)

> Flies! The landlord had no opinion whatever of those puny hooks with little tufts of feather upon them, which Mr Howard called flies. He would like to show them something that was a fly indeed: a marvel of mechanism, wound up by clock-work and kept thus in motion for twenty minutes at a time. That *was* a fly, ...

It's clear from the context that the phrase "had no opinion whatever of" means "did not think highly of" here, and given the context, I believe its use in *Benjamin Bunny* means the same thing.

<sup>1</sup> I would have used "thought very little of", but in the context of the original phrase, it's too ambiguous.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that "old Mr. Bunny set cats at naught"?

Answer (score 10):

The explicit meaning of the sentence is that Old Mr. Bunny did not have an opinion either good or bad or complex or nuanced about cats, that he just didn't think of cats at all. The intended meaning is that he wasn't scared of cats, differently than one might expect of any rabbit.

Comment: *No opinion of cats* is not the same as *no opinion on cats*.

Comment: @TimLymington: What about 'about'? And what _is_ the difference exactly?

Comment: *About* is the same as *on*, as I use the language. And *of* is explicitly different in certain circumstances; you may have *a low opinion of* cats, but not **a low opinion about* them. On the other hand, you can have *a strong opinion about/on* them, but not *of*.  (The second sentence of your answer is clearly right, but doesn't seem to follow from the first.)

Comment: @TimLymington: The 2nd sentence follows from the first in that if he _were_ scared, then he would definitely be thinking of cats to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

If you *don't think much of* something, you have a low opinion of it. Here the phrase is intensified: Old Mr Bunny had such a low opinion of cats that he didn't hesitate to attack one.

Answer (score 1):

In British English, they use *whatever* where an American would be more apt to use *what**so**ever*, with an extra *so* packed in there.  It means he had no opinion about them at all.

Comment: Thanks! In the context could it mean "he wasn't scared of cats"?

Comment: @TEd Perhaps.⁠⁠⁠

Comment: Comparting NGrams for [British](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+opinion+whatever%2Cno+opinion+whatsoever&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) against [American](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+opinion+whatever%2Cno+opinion+whatsoever&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) usage for *"no opinion whatever/whatsoever"* doesn't suggest any significant US/UK difference. All I see is that the dominant *"whatever"* is on the wane, so relatively speaking, *"whatsoever"* is gaining ground.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The difference is that to an American, *no opinion whatever* has come to sound ungrammatical/broken/foreign/confusing/mysterious. I have never heard an American say something like that. We would just say *no opinion **at all***, unless we wanted to go over the top and add in the *-so-* particle to have *no opinion **whatsoever***.  There is also room for an infix emphatic particle like *no opinion **whatso#$%!@ever***.

Comment: Taking the more common collocation **nothing what(so)ever**, I still don't see any significant difference between [British](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nothing+whatever%2Cnothing+whatsoever&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) and [American](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nothing+whatever%2Cnothing+whatsoever&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) trends or prevalence. And on both sides of the pond, **nothing at all** has always been far more common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I know what you say you see, but I also know what I know I hear.  “Nothing whatever” does not make sense to an American.  It sounds funny.

Comment: Well, "nothing what(so)ever" is clearly a steeply declining usage in both countries over the last century. I can't say either version sounds particularly "funny" to me, but for something like this I certainly wouldn't go out on a limb and claim that other Brits would either agree or disagree. Having said that, although the single-word response *"Whatever"* is also perfectly common among younger Brits, I must say that one sounds typically "American" to me.