# Confused about How to Describe Feelings

Tags: expressions

I'm confused how to describe one of my feelings.

For example, I don't like drinking coffee, but I don't hate it either. I just can live without it. In my country, we would probably say "I don't have any feelings about coffee". Could you please tell me what's the common way of saying "I don't have any feelings about coffee" in English? Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: *Cool, indifferent, uncaring, casual, uninterested* ...

Comment: I'd go with **indifferent to coffee**.

Comment: I can take it or leave it.

Comment: Not an answer but entirely relevant: ["Old Mr Bunny had no opinion whatever of cats"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59103/old-mr-bunny-had-no-opinion-whatever-of-cats-what-does-it-mean)

Answer (score 1):

Consider **[Neutral](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/neutral)**

> Of no particular kind, characteristics

So you might choose to say:" I felt neutral towards coffee"

Answer (score 0):

Two common English idioms
"couldn't care less" and 
"could care less"
would apply.

> I couldn't care less about coffee.

or

> I could care less about coffee.

Usage notes:
http://blog.dictionary.com/could-care-less/